# What is the maximum number of Star Trek TOS characters to appear in one shot in a Star Trek property?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, star-trek-tos

A (correctly) deleted answer by @EatMe to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113375/are-these-two-women-existing-star-trek-characters) was interesting enough in its own right for me to ask this new question.

The deleted answer contained this photo:

[image: Star Trek V courtroom]

The photo shows a courtroom scene from *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home* where all seven of the TOS "major players" walk in, and two other known characters are in the background.  Mark Lenard, playing Sarek, is seated in the courtroom, but doesn't count as being "in the shot" as he is obscured by the actors walking in.

Is 9 the maximum number of TOS characters in one shot of a live-action Star Trek property, and if not, what is?

To clarify : Any named character from any TOS episode **script** "counts".  But they have to be **real** character names.  "Spectator in the third row picking his nose" **does not** count. Characters that only appeared in the movies do not count.

Comment: Are you including TOS episodes? And do you mean in one frame only?

Comment: What exactly counts as a "character"? You don't seem to be including the extras at the back, so does the person need a name? Spoken dialogue? Some other level of notability?

Comment: @PrincessAda If the extras at the back were named in a Star Trek TOS episode, then they would count.   Star Trek IV is not TOS.

Comment: @JonCuster _any_ live-action Star Trek property, but _only_ TOS characters.

Comment: It would be better to have the answer in an answer, not in the question.

Comment: @OrangeDog I see a benchmark, not an answer.  Nevertheless, I tried to make it as "questiony" as possible originally, but the photo was edited in later by someone else.

Comment: @Spencer then your answer is just going to be "yes, that one".

Comment: @OrangeDog Notice I asked "how many" and not "which shot". Perhaps a few frames before or after, Sarek appears and then the answer will be "No, it's 10, not 9".

Comment: @Spencer you can very easily check that yourself.

Comment: Think Chapel was a doctor by the start of TMP

Comment: Also what counts as 'cast'? E.g., is the character Dr. M'Benga in *TOS* part of the original cast? What about Harry Mudd?

Comment: @Lexible Either one would count. They are both named characters.

Comment: @Spencer:  I suspect this is a fool's errand because a name can be assigned to most extras if someone suffiently nerdy and motivated takes up the task.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Extras by definition don't have names.

Comment: Do we count Admiral Cartwright (who appears to be sitting on Rand's right)?  He's a character in both *Star Trek IV* and *Star Trek VI*.  What about other named characters who are just in this movie?  Where's the cut-off?

Comment: @DavidW The movies are not TOS. Was Admiral Cartwright in a TOS episode?  That's the cutoff.

Comment: I'm guessing any time the bridge is busy you are going to see a lot of people. Here are [9 regular characters](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pocket_TNG_characters?file=USS_Enterprise-D_bridge_crew%2C_2364.jpg) on the bridge of TNG not counting the 3 extras in the backgroun (who may or may not be recurring extras).

Comment: @JackBNimble As ThePopMachine says, "if someone suffiently nerdy and motivated takes up the task"...